# How to backspace into a partial completion in emacs icicles

Tags: emacs, icicles

When using emacs (24.3) with icicles, if I do something like

```
M-x find-file <RET> foo <TAB><TAB>
```

the `*Completion*` buffer pops up and I can cycle through completions. In the minibuffer "foo" is now underlined (I think because of  `Icicle Match Highlight Minibuffer` face).  At this point there are two behaviours that puzzle me:

1. If I want to further refine my prefix, I can only type one character, further characters overwrite this newly typed character unless I hit `<TAB>` after each subsequent character.  I.e.
    `M-x find-file foo <TAB><TAB>ba<TAB>` the "a" will overwrite the "b", and the subsequent `<TAB>` will show matches for `fooa*`
   Why can't I type multiple subsequent characters?
2. If, say, `"foo"` was incorrect, and I want to change it to `"fop"`, I can't just backspace into the prefix(which is showing as underlined in minibuffer).  It seems I can only delete the entire prefix and start over.  Is there a way to backspace into the underlined prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give a more complete recipe to reproduce your problem, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (i.e., no init file, loading only [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles), and specifying any non-default **Icicles** option values needed to reproduce the problem).

For example, by default, `*Completions*` is not popped up just by typing text in the minibuffer.  Did you hit `TAB`? `S-TAB`?

And you will not see underlining in the minibuffer unless you are cycling among candidates.
If you are cycling among candidates then the current candidate is inserted in the minibuffer, and the matched part is underlined.

It's not clear what you are saying: "unless I hit after each subsequent character". Unless you hit what?

In general, I have trouble following (guessing) what you are doing. Try to write down just what you do, step by step. And mention the command names you see in `*Completions*` when you complete your test input.

You can also contact me by email: `M-x icicle-send-bug-report`.

If I had to guess, I'd suggest that reading [this section](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Cycling_Completions) of the doc might help you.  Dunno.

---

**UPDATE**

I think I know what you are trying to describe, and the answer is *at the end* of [***this section***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#CancelingMinibufferInteraction) of the **Icicles** doc.

That text explains that if you use **`delete-selection-mode`** and if option `icicle-point-position-in-candidate` or option `icicle-mark-position-in-candidate` is such that part of the cycled candidate is automatically selected, then any text you type *replaces the selection*.

This is the normal behavior of `delete-selection-mode`.  It is a feature.  If you do not want to replace the active region then, as usual, use `C-g` to deactivate it.  If you find yourself doing this often then consider whether you might prefer a different value for one of those two options.

[This](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#toc2) small doc section might also help. It is about using `delete-selection-mode` with **Icicles**. And [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#toc10) short section is about those options and the region and cycling.

Comment: Ugh, my formatting was badly messed up. `<TAB>` doesn't show up at all if it's not marked as code.  Fixed the question to clarify

Comment: See my answer, after **UPDATE**. I think it explains things. I'm guessing you have `delete-selection-mode` turned on, and the unmatched part of the current cycling candidate is therefore selected. When you type a character, it replaces the active region. Use `C-g` if you do not want that. See the doc I pointed you to and the options I mentioned, which affect the region. (The first `TAB` performs completion; the second cycles.)

Comment: And again, I think your description is not accurate. I think you will understand that when you get the point about the active region (determined by those two user options). It is not the prefix that is deleted when you hit Backspace; it is the suffix, i.e., the active region, i.e., the text between `icicle-point-position-in-candidate` and `icicle-mark-position-in-candidate`.

Comment: If I'm wrong in my guess, then try to give a more precise recipe, and mention any **Icicles** options that are not at their default values.

Comment: When I try to interpret and follow your recipe I do not see behavior similar to what you describe. But then you do not mention what the matching file names are in `*Completions*` etc. I know only that `foo` must be the longest common prefix among them, since that is what is underlined. (It is easier to discuss things by email; SO is not really made for that. If my answer does not help you, use `M-x icicle-send-bug-report` to send me an email.)

Comment: Your suggestion to try emacs -Q led me to the problem, which is conflict between cua and icicles.  I see now the warnings at [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Binding_Discussion) regarding use of cua and icicles.

Comment: 1. There is no conflict, because you can customize the **Icicles** key bindings. There is a conflict only wrt the default key bindings. 2. Consider accepting the answer, since it answered your question. Thx.